# Django display DateFormat as dd/mm/yyyy

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a form in Django where the user needs to select the date. When the user selects the date the date is displayed in the following format mm/dd/yyyy (eg. 02/29/2024).
I want the date in the form to be displayed as dd/mm/yyyy (eg. 29/02/2024 ).

This is the date field in my form:
 `date = forms.DateField( widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d/%m/%Y', attrs={'type': 'date', 'min': str(timezone.now().date()), 'max': str((timezone.now() + timedelta(days=365)).date())}), help_text='Select a date', input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'], validators=[validate_future_date], )`

I also tried:
In settings.py:
`DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d-%m-%Y',) USE_I18N = True USE_L10N = True`

In the form:
`input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS,`

After both of these approaches the format was still displayed as dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: Since you use `USE_I18N` it will let the locale of the browser take precedence, so the `DATE_INPUT_FORMAT`, is only relevant if no locale is known.

Comment: Also. Letting the locale of the browser take precedence is harmonious with user preferences. Of course if you care for user experience in this circumstance.